# How can I detect when my app receives focus in a split view in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

My win8.1 store app navigates the user to a web browser. The user can interact with the browser, but when they return to my app, I need it to detect this so it can refresh its content (and take into consideration any changes done on the server).

This is easy if the browser launches in fullscreen, but when it is split, I need to detect whenever the user taps in my app window. (Seems that it is launched as split by default, which is actually the preferred experience).

```
-------------------------------
|             |               |
|             |               |
|    my app   |    browser    |
|             |               |
|             |               |
-------------------------------
```

QUESTION - What event can I use to detect when the user taps to change the focus from the browser to my app?

I tried GotFocus for the Page, but didn't get called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event that you seem to be looking for is [Window.Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.activated):

> This event occurs when a Window has been activated or deactivated by the system. An app can determine what the status of the Window activation is by checking the WindowActivatedEventArgs.WindowActivationState property. A Window could be visible on screen but not be active (for example, in snapped apps). Additionally, if any other parts of the system takes focus away from the window, this event will occur. This could happen as a result of user interaction or code, and the WindowActivationState will indicate which action has taken place.

Juste be aware that this event will fire when the window gets *and* loses focus. So you'll have to test the event args to determine what's happening.

You can get the instance of the current window with [Window.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.current.aspx).

Comment: Weird naming, but yes, this worked beautifully. The one oddity was that I wasn't able to fire message dialogs from the handler --- but that's ok it was just for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

If the user clicks back to your app the `OnGotFocus` will raised and you can do your stuff.

```
public sealed partial class HubPage : Page
{
    private bool hasFocus = true;    

    protected async override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);

        if (!hasFocus)
        {
            var msg = new MessageDialog("Focus", "Focus");
            await msg.ShowAsync();
            hasFocus = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);

        hasFocus = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all, but thanks. i even tried it in a brand new store app project and set breakpoints. the functions never get called.

Comment: Me too. brand new win 8.1 app. function gets called if I click or tap into the spitted app. tried on machine and simulator.

Comment: strange. can you provide the full code including xamls? the above is missing the InitializeComponent() call, so it is incomplete...

Comment: [Downloadlink](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8394450/App1.zip.html) Uploaded my Projectfile.

Comment: Did you miss something? I searched for "OnLostFocus" in your entire solution, and it came up empty.

Comment: Wrong zip file sorry use this: [Downloadlink](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8416282/App1.zip.html)